# Share iOS development.provision file

Tags: ios, testing, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning

Is it ok to share the iOS development.provision file with others ?

can this be misused and get me in trouble ? be banned from developer portal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms of use specifically state who you can share provisioning profiles with. It may vary slightly between single member and enterprise accounts, but it basically amounts to saying that you can only share provisioning profiles with members of your development team / company, or clients.

You can check exactly what it says by signing in to your Apple Developer account, clicking "Your Account" at the top, then clicking "Legal Agreements" on the left.